# Enviar dados via POST em javascript

Tags: php, javascript, post

Galera eu sei quase nada de JS, e eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema em php com ajuda do Cakephp 3, a seguir é parte da minha tela de pagamento, o meu problema é que eu preciso pegar os valores que estão em Javascript do total_venda, e pegar tambem a quantidade de produtos que esta em php na minha session id_cart e passar para js para enviar via post assim que eu clicasse no botão fechar venda. 
Eu não estou sabendo como pegar esse dado na minha view e nem trata-la na minha controller.

Minha modal:

```
    <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl" style="width: 90%; font-size: 130%;">Pagar Venda</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width:90%">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">Formas de Pagamento</h2>                        
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <br />
                    <table class="payment-methods">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="payment_methods" id="dinheiro" class="pg" />
                                <label for="dinheiro" class="labelpag">
                                    <img src="/projeto/img/cash.png" class="imgpag" alt="" >
                                </label>
                                <br />
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="payment_methods" id="credito" class="pg" />
                                <label for="credito" class="labelpag2">
                                    <img src="/projeto/img/card2.png" class="imgpag2">
                                </label>
                            </td>
                            <br />
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="payment_methods" id="debito" class="pg" />
                                <label for="debito" class="labelpag2">
                                    <img src="/projeto/img/card.png" class="imgpag2">
                                </label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p class="p_pagamento totalpago">Total de Itens:
                                <?php
                                $id = $_SESSION['id_cart'];
                                $id = $id["id"];
                                    if(isset($id)){
                                        if($id == null){
                                            $id = 0;
                                        }
                                        echo count($id);?>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="produtos_id" value="$id">
                                    <?php
                                    } ?>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p class="p_pagamento">Total da Venda: R$ <span class="total_venda"></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 
                                <p class="p_pagamento"> Total Pago: R$ <input type="" name="troco" value="" class="input_pagamento" id="total_pago"></p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               <p class="p_pagamento trocopagamento"> Troco R$ 
                                <span id="troco"></span></p> 
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                        <br />
                        <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="click">Fechar Venda</button>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal footer 
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Js:

```
<script>
function soma_total(){
    total = 0;
    $(".total_unitario").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    $(".total_venda").text((total).toFixed(2));
    total_venda = $(".total_venda").text((total).toFixed(2));
};

var quantidade = 0;
var precounitario = 0;
var total = 0;

$(".quant").each(function(){
    quantidade = parseFloat($(this).val());
    precounitario = parseFloat($(this).parent().parent().find(".preco_uni").text());
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".total_unitario").text((quantidade*precounitario).toFixed(2));
    soma_total();
})

$(".quant").change(function(){
    quantidade = parseFloat($(this).val());
    precounitario = parseFloat($(this).parent().parent().find(".preco_uni").text());
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".total_unitario").text((quantidade*precounitario).toFixed(2));
    soma_total();
});


$("#total_pago").keyup(function(){
    var pago = $(this).val().replace(",",".");
    $("#troco").text((pago-total).toFixed(2));        
})
```

Comment: Você já tem a array/variável pronta que recebe os dados? No caso seria apenas passar os dados para outra página via _POST ou também tem limitações em montar essas variáveis?

Comment: No caso seria para mandar os dados para minha controller e ela poder salvar no banco de dados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem algumas maneiras de enviar posts para o servidor através do javascript. O ideal é que você utilize formulários no próprio html, entretanto para o envio do post diretamente pelo javascript, a maneira mais simples, é utilizando a função [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), da biblioteca jQuery (que você já utiliza). Essa função é responsável por executar uma solicitação HTTP assíncrona (em outras palavras, permite enviar e tratar o resultado das requisições ao servidor). Veja o exemplo:

```js
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "servidor.php",
   data: {nome: "Lucas"}
});
```

Vale lembrar que a mensagem é, por padrão, enviada como um JSON. Portanto em seu servidor você deve tomar o cuidado necessário para ler essa mensagem. No caso do PHP, utilize a função [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php).

No seu código, o script deverá ficar da seguinte forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // aqui vai seu código já criado

    $("#click").on("click", function(){ // Quando o elemento do id "click" é clicado...
        var id_cart = $("#produtos_id").val(); // Pega o valor do campo produtos_id
        var total_venda = $(".total_venda").text(); // Pega o total

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "servidor.php",
            data: {idCart: id_cart, totalVenda: total_venda} // Dados a serem enviados
        });
    });
});
```

Na página html, é importante adicionar o id `produtos_id` ao campo de mesmo name, caso contrário o jQuery não conseguirá pegar o value do campo. Veja o antes e depois:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="produtos_id" value="$id">
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="produtos_id" name="produtos_id" value="$id">
```

Comment: Utilizei este codigo, fiz alguns teste e verifiquei que script ele as variaveis declaradas como total_venda estao passando os dados, porém quando tento finalizar a compra da erro de variavel nao definida... Talvez possa ser erro na minha controller mas aparentemente esta tudo certo

Comment: Olá amigo, tente fechar o span total_venda no seu código html. Ele deverá ficar assim: `<p class="p_pagamento">Total da Venda: R$ <span class="total_venda"></span></p>`. Acredito que o erro seja na hora de pegar o texto desse span, visto que a tag está sem fechamento.

Comment: Lucas, entao verifiquei, fiz o seu código e arrumei a controller, o programa roda nao apresenta erros porém a controller nao esta recebendo o post do js e aparentemente o codigo esta correto.

Comment: Coloquei o meu código no comentário seguinte e mostrando o problema, obrigada pela ajuda